# Runit and ClouldStack python API - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, daemon

I am using a python ClouldStack API to connect to my clould provider.

```
 cloudstack = CloudStack.Client()
```

In $HOME I have to create the following file with my api credentials e.g.

```
/root/.cloudstack
```

If I run a python script from  root from the command line..it works.  But, when running the script using runit, I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtb_remote_services/remote_chef_dp_redis_monitor.py", line 27, in <module>
    import chefUtilities as chefu
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/classes/chefUtilities.py", line 29, in <module>
    import dpClouldStack as dpu
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/classes/dpClouldStack.py", line 1, in <module>
    import CloudStack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CloudStack-0.1-py2.7.egg/CloudStack/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CloudStack-0.1-py2.7.egg/CloudStack/Client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from BaseClient import BaseClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CloudStack-0.1-py2.7.egg/CloudStack/BaseClient.py", line 12, in <module>
    config_file = env + '/.cloudstack'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Here is what my runit run file looks like.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.py >> /tmp/remote_chef_elb_monitor.out 2>&1
```

So...is runit running under root?  If so, would it not file /root/.cloudstack?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run the runit file "manually"?

Answer (score 0):

**As you don't show code,** I can only help in so far as I can tell your `env` variable is `None`. Either you get it from a function where it is not returned correctly under all circumstances, or something else goes wrong.

Comment: Here is how I connect..cloudstack = CloudStack.Client(). By default, the api always looks in $HOME with a file name of .cloudstack.